# Node.JS reading BLOB from mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, base64, blob

I'm using the Node.JS node-mysql module. One column has a BLOB type and want to read from it and if possible base64 encode it. I haven't been able to find anything on how to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try the following snippet:

```
var buffer = new Buffer( blob );
var bufferBase64 = buffer.toString('base64');
```

If your blob is binary, use the following instead:

```
var buffer = new Buffer( blob, 'binary' );
var bufferBase64 = buffer.toString('base64');
```

You can also simplify that to one line:

```
var bufferBase64 = new Buffer( blob, 'binary' ).toString('base64');
```

Comment: blob is undefined!

Comment: `new Buffer` is depreciated now - use `Buffer.from()`

Comment: @RozzA  Buffer.from(blob,'binary').toString(); is that okay to convert Blob into string.

Answer (score 22):

Of note: **mysql-node automatically converts Blob objects** into javascript Buffer objects.
The above answer addresses base64 encoding.

For me, the simplest way to just read it as a string in node was:
`myObject.myBlobAttr.toString('utf-8')`

---

*As of Jan 28, 2015,*
From Felix's [mysql-node page](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#buffer):

**Type casting**

For your convenience, this driver will cast mysql types into native JavaScript types by default. The following mappings exist:

...

**Buffer**

TINYBLOB
MEDIUMBLOB
LONGBLOB
BLOB
BINARY
VARBINARY
BIT (last byte will be filled with 0 bits as necessary)

---

**Edit**
Alternate option for UTF-8 (?)

`String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(myObject.myBlobAttr));`